# How many ways are there to arrange the train?

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $14$ intermediate stations between city $A$ and city $B$ on a rail  track. A train is to be arranged from $A$ to $B$ so that it halts at exactly $3$ intermediate stations, no two of which are consecutive. Then the number of ways of doing so ....

My try: $\binom{14}3$ ways to choose $3$ stations from $14$, and $14-1$ are consecutive among them, so delete them. Thus, $\binom{14}3-(14-1)$ ways. But, my book says it is $$\binom{14}{3}-\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}+\binom{12}1$$

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write

$$\binom{14}{3} - \binom{13}{1}$$

This is wrong, because even though stations $E,F$ are consecutive, you need to remove them more than once, because there are multiple possible ways in which both those tracks are visited.

$$A,E,F\quad B,E,F, \text{et cetera}$$

Now how many are there for each consecutive pair? $\binom{12}{1}$ obviously, you just choose another station(among $A,B,C,D,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N$. in our example)

So our answer *would* be $$\binom{14}{3}-\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}$$

But what's the catch?

We have subtracted the pairs $A,B,C$ , $B,C,D$ **twice** but they were only counted once in our first term. So just add them back to bring the total to $0$.

$$\binom{14}{3}-\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}+\binom{12}{1}$$

Comment: The question says A is first station and B is last. So, how can A,E,F or B,E,F be consecutive?

Comment: @Sush okay. I used my own notation. Take the stations as $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N$

Comment: Just the last question: Will you please elaborate why did we add $\binom{12}1$? Are you talking about pair (A,B,C) and (B,C,D)?

Comment: @Sush yes. 12 such pairs(proper term would be triples).

Comment: The $-\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}$ accounts for patterns ...X...YZ... or ...XY...Z... where the ... may be empty. But this assumes that the position of the XY pair is unique. This fails for the situation ...XYZ... = ...(XY)Z... = ...X(YZ)... That is, this pattern has been subtracted twice and must be added back once. Thanks to [ccorn](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/75794/ccorn).

Comment: @Sush so you understand now? :)

Comment: :) Yes. Sorry, my bad English might be hurdle! I am thankful to you.